# Flutter Errors, Another exception was thrown: Invalid argument(s) AND Another exception was thrown: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget

Tags: flutter, dart, runtime-error

**I need to create a new account everytime to contribute to stack overflow!
This is STUPID!!! PLS!!! Fix your rating system!!! I have 5 and 1/2 years EXP.

Seriously... And I am not allowed to ask or post questions or solutions...**

---

Flutter was returning these errors and nobody has offered the below solution.

Error 1 : 
**Another exception was thrown: Invalid argument(s)**

Error 2 : 
**Another exception was thrown: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget**

I kept running into this problem because the data for **ParentDataWidget**
was not yet loaded and I was accessing it.

---

**My Solution :** 
Create a variable

```
bool isLoaded = false;
```

IF : **isLoaded = false** 
Do not render the screen.

IF : **isLoaded = true** 
Render the screen

**// 1: Set your state**

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      
    );
  }
}
```

**// 2: Get all your variables** (WHEN YOU HAVE YOUR DATA FROM YOUR LAST CALL)

```
 // This will be my final call in my methods for this page
 Future getWhateverDataMethod() async {
    //Magic happens over here and you get all your data.


    // When you have your data you need. Then set the isLoaded var

    isLoaded = true;
}
```

**// 3 : Load your page**

**NOW, when you load your screen your data is ready to be rendered and your error will disappear**

Comment: are you asking and  answering  on question section?

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect use of `ParentDataWidget` error is the UI issue... it will never resolved with functionality....

Comment: None the less this removed my error popping up on the UI. So it's not a good implementation. But I already changed up the UI and did read the docs and cant seem to get rid of it until I loaded the data for the widget. If I load before I get an error. If I load after I don't...